# Spring Initializr - running the first application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

Started learning Spring framework, but I have a problem where by my project builds successfully but it wont finish running...

**pom file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.sivcodes</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-example</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-boot-example</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**SpringBootExampleApplication.java**

```
package com.sivcodes;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootExampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootExampleApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

[Picture of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsXzi.png)

I have searching the internet for the answer but nothing relevant comes up.

Comment: And why should it? It is a server application (you included `spring-boot-starter-web`), if it would shutdown directly nothing would be able to connect to it.

Comment: Everything works as it should, there is nothing to stop. Or do you want to stop your webserver running immediately after start?

Comment: Thank you guys for pointing that out. I think I didn't clearly explain the problem I have.

but I  found the solution to it, the port 8080 is being used by another service.

Comment: Don't know what you're saying, the Tomcat status log of your picture tells that Tomcat is running on port 8080, so there can't be another service using that specific port. That's impossible by design.